# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) when using discord.py

Tags: python, json, discord.py

im coding a pretty common part of the bot where it can have multiple prefixes for different servers, the default being '|'.

when i run the bot and invite it to a server this is what i get when it joins:

```
Ignoring exception in on_guild_join
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 270, in _run_event
        await coro(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\amit2\source\repos\LAKRIS bot\LAKRIS bot\LAKRIS_bot.py", line 19, in on_guild_join
        prefixes = json.load(f)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
        parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
        raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

my code is:

```
 def get_prefix(bot, message):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

bot = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = get_prefix)

@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = '|'

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
```

i tried moving some stuff around but its the first time im actually working with json so im not really sure what to try.

edit: here is my project files.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ8ta.png)

Comment: What's actually in that json file?  Remember that empty files are not valid json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this means there is a syntax error in your "prefixes.json" file.

It doesn't contain valid json - the first character is invalid according to the exception.

The image shows the file is 0 bytes - an empty file isn't valid json - you need to put some json into the file.

Comment: i added the project file to the question, can you see something i missed? thanks

Comment: yep, that was the problem. forgot the {}.